# Unable to receive responses from DHCP servers to a DCHP discover packet crafted in Scapy

Tags: python, scapy

I'm trying to send a DHCP Discover packet using scapy over the network. I have two DHCP Servers on My LAN but got no answers.

Here is the packet:

```
fm, hw= get_if_raw_hwaddr(scapy.all.conf.iface)
DHCPDiscover = Ether(dst="ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff", src=hw)/IP(src="0.0.0.0",dst="255.255.255.255") / UDP(sport=68,dport=67)/BOOTP(op=1, chaddr=hw)/DHCP(options=[("message-type","discover"),("end")])
ans, unans = srp(DHCPDiscover)
```

Output:

> Received 23909 packets, got 0 answers, remaining 1 packets

Answer (score 1):

Solved! The problem I think was on the `srp()` function. It can't receive packets on port 68, but I've created a new function with a new thread that sniffs for `BOOTP` messages and displays the packet fields.